# Finding rotation matrix to transform one (3-vector) basis to another in 3d

Tags: python, matrix

We have basis in 3d, `Vx` = (1,0,0), `Vy` = (0,1,0), `Vz`=(0,0,1), which is transforming by (rotation) matrix M to `Vx'`, `Vy'`, `Vz'` respectively. So we have 3 equations:

```
M * Vx = Vx'
M * Vy = Vy'
M * Vz = Vz'
```

Thus we have 9 linear equations for 9 components of matrix M.
Now I need to transform this equation in form `A * m = b` (to solve it with numpy i.e.), where m is column-vectors of unknown `M` components like `[m11, m12, m13, m21, ...]`, `A` is coefficients matrix, `b` is coefficients column-vector.

So the question is, what are formulas for `A` and `b` ? Is it possible to write some matrix formulas for it?

=== UPDATE

I got 'Notable question' prize for this question so I am updating it to unblock. Please note the question is quite precise and I am not searching any tool, the phrase 'Or, is there any tool which will help to write per-component formulas?' is just small addition which is not matter a lot I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `V0 = np.array([Vx,Vy,Vz])` for the old basis, `V1 = np.array([Vx1,Vy1,Vz1])` for the new basis, where the basis vectors are the matrix rows and have the relation for the transposed matrices where the basis vectors are the columns

```
M * V0.T = V1.T  <==>  V0 * M.T = V1
```

This can be nicely solved as

```
M = np.linalg.solve(V0,V1).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty easy.

Matrix A is

```
    |Vx 000 000|
    |000 Vx 000|
A = |000 000 Vx|
    |Vy 000 000|
    |000 Vy 000|
        ....
```

considering `Vx` in this notation is 3 scalars `Vx1, Vx2, Vx2` (x,y,z components of Vx), so matrix is 9x9.

b is vertically stacked column-vectors from V' components

```
    |Vx'|
b = |Vy'|
    |Vz'|
```

Here is final solution with Python/numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def solve_3vector_equation(v1, v2, v3, v1_, v2_, v3_):
    """
    Solves linear equation system:
        M * v1 = v1_
        M * v2 = v2_
        M * v3 = v3_

    Where M is 3x3 matrix, v... - 3d vectors
    """

    A = np.zeros((9, 9))

    vs = [v1, v2, v3]
    vs_ = [v1_, v2_, v3_]

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            A[i * 3 + j, j * 3:(j + 1) * 3] = vs[i]

    b = np.hstack(vs_)

    return np.linalg.solve(A, b).reshape((3, 3))
```